# How to break a datatable in mutliple single rows datable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a dataTable d, I want to break it into multiple tables of single rows.

I tried it by using GroupBy but it's giving me an exception

```
List<DataTable> subTables = d.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(ro => ro.Field<int>("InstanceId")).Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable()).ToList()It's
```

> Its throwing an exception Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: I doubt you really need to "break it into multiple tables". Sounds like an xy problem. What do you need to actually accomplish?

Comment: @Crowcoder actually after getting a single row as a table from this i  will get another datatable on the basis of InstanceId in this table which is actually the child of this single row dataTable then i can join them representing child and parent

Comment: Why not just use RowFilter or maybe DataViews?

Answer (score 0):

there was a little mess from my side as here

```
GroupBy(ro => ro.Field<int>("InstanceId")).Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
```

Field `InstanceId` was of type `string` and i was casting it to `int`  so reverting it to

```
GroupBy(ro => ro.Field<string>("InstanceId")).Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
```

solve the issue